# DatabaseError: ORA-01555: snapshot too old

Tags: python, sql, oracle

Data that I wanted to download was about 45,000,000 rows and 38 columns in Oracle 11g database.

When I tried to download the data with chunksize=50000 in python,

> DatabaseError: ORA-01555: snapshot too old

this error occur always at the same point of the chunk(code(1)_at 9th session).

However, when I downloaded the same data separately by date, the data downloaded without any error.(code(2))

At the first time, I guessed "DatabaseError: ORA-01555" this error was because downloading by chunksize 50000 might take too long. But data for one day had about 300,000 rows which was bigger than 50000 chunksize. Can anyone tell me about your opinion?

Below are my codes.

(1) Download by chunk size

```
# SQL Query
tmp = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Database WHERE TIME_STAMP BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-12-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-12-31 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')", con = con, chunksize = 50000)
gen = map(pd.DataFrame, tmp)

# Download by chunk
cnt = 0
flag = 0
for index, data in enumerate(gen):
    if flag == 0 or index == 0:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        flag = 1
    elif index % 100 != 0:
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(data)], axis = 0)        
    elif index % 100 == 0:
        df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(data)], axis = 0)   
        cnt = cnt+1

        # Save as CSV file
        df.to_csv("{0}{1}{2}".format("D:\\Data",cnt,".csv"), header=True, index=False)
        print("Index: ", index)
        print("Shape: ", df.shape)
        print("==========={}th Session Ended==============".format(cnt))

        # Flush out Memory
        del df
        gc.collect()
        flag = 0
```

(Always at 9th Session, the error came out)

(2) Download by date

```
for i in range(1,32):
    print("============ 2019-12-",i," ============")
    date = "2019-12-{}".format(i)

    # SQL Query
    tmp = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Database WHERE TIME_STAMP BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-12-{} 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-12-{} 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')".format(i,i), con = con)

    # Save as CSV file
    tmp.to_csv("{0}{1}{2}{3}".format("D:\\","ByDate\\",date,".csv"), header=True, index=False)

    # Flush out Memory
    del tmp
    gc.collect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch your query, Oracle must keep a logically consistent view of it from that moment in time until it finishes responding. As the underlying data is changing through user transactions, Oracle maps the deltas in rollback segments and undo space. If too much data changes and the undo space is exhausted Oracle can no longer maintain that consistent view of your requested data and has to abandon the query - thus the error you're seeing. See here: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01555_snapshot_old.htm

Unless you can modify the database to allow more undo space for transactions you're likely going to have to wait to run your query when the database is idle or take your data in much smaller chunks.

Comment: Oh, I thought that I misunderstood the **pd.read_sql_query** part.  Before I read your explanation, In code(1), I thought that if I set the chunksize option, pd.read_sql_query just saved the queries in iterator, not actually sent them at that time.


So,I thought, the actual query(select * by chunk) is actually sent  to Oracle when I iterate the iterator that contained the query.(inside the for loop)
However, based on your explanation, all the queries are sent at once, outside the for loop.

Comment: So am I right to understand like below?
>code (1): Snapshot was taken at this time.

`tmp = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Database ~~", con = con, chunksize = 50000)`
(SQL query was sent outside of the for loop.)

>code (2): Snapshot was taken at this time.
`tmp = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM Database ~~".format(i,i), con = con)`
(SQL query was sent at each time inside the for loop)

Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. code(1) has a much bigger result set that is taking too long for the database to return because of other user activity/transactions making changes. code(2) succeeds because it asks for much smaller result sets at a time. You might get code(1) to work by returning rows in larger sets (much bigger than 50,000 at a time).